# Integrate One Signal API with Firebase Cloud Fuctions

Tags: javascript, firebase, mobile, google-cloud-functions, onesignal

Integrating Onesignal API with Firebase Cloud Functions

Hello Everybody,

I want to enable push notifications for my mobile app (Android, iOS) that is working with  realtime firebase database, in this moment i'm sending push notifications from both platforms Android/iOS with one signal, but i want to do this task  from firebase cloud fuctions.

I know that there a onesignal sdk for JS, but i have problems to figuere out how to configure my cloud fuctions, because this is not a server like other normal servers. Rather it, as I see it, is an interface where scripts are uploaded.

So I'm confused about it, and even more because i am a mobile developer, i have not much expirience with this kind of architecture with JS and cloud.

I need just a clue to figure out how implement it please, or know if this is posible this idea or i have to think on another solution.

I'am really thankfully for your help and  support.

Comment: Hey, I'm looking to do same thing, did you find solution?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully not too late of a reply to be useful.

You should be able to use something very similar to the NodeJS code provided in the [OneSignal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#section-send-based-on-filters-tags-create-notification)

```
var sendNotification = function(data) {
  var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization": "Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj"
  };

  var options = {
    host: "onesignal.com",
    port: 443,
    path: "/api/v1/notifications",
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers
  };

  var https = require('https');
  var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
    res.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log("Response:");
      console.log(JSON.parse(data));
    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });

  req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
  req.end();
};

var message = { 
  app_id: "5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c",
  contents: {"en": "English Message"},
  include_player_ids: ["6392d91a-b206-4b7b-a620-cd68e32c3a76","76ece62b-bcfe-468c-8a78-839aeaa8c5fa","8e0f21fa-9a5a-4ae7-a9a6-ca1f24294b86"]
};

sendNotification(message);
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error in firebase console functions: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND onesignal.com onesignal.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'onesignal.com',
  host: 'onesignal.com',
  port: 443 }

Comment: @LucasRT I remember that some time ago the case was that free plans couldn't send requests to external domains. Maybe this is the case. 
Oh, the comment is from 5 years ago, probably this was the case :P